What's the purpose of "[0]" appended to a match method in ruby?
I was going through the Exception Handling chapter of the Bastards Book of Ruby and I came across a bit of code in between the lines of:
while 1
    puts "Enter a number>>"
    num = Kernel.gets.match(/\d+/)[0]
    puts "#{num} + 1 is: #{num.to_i + 1}"
end

I'm unable to grasp the purpose of [0] appended to the match method in the num variable. What does it do here?

Thanks a lot. I was confused because of how array indexing was working for MatchData which is supposed to be an object.

Don't assume [] implies an array. String#[] returns sub-strings, Integer#[] returns bit slices, Proc#[] calls the proc, it really depends on the receiver. And it's perfectly fine to define custom operator methods in your own classes (if it fits your needs), see the examples in the docs for Methods (right after the operator list).

while 1 ? Very strange for Ruby code. loop do is fine.

Yeah I thought that too LOL. It was an example in the book.


I'm unable to grasp the purpose of [0]

In Ruby, [0] is a method call. What a method does depends on the receiver. In addition, arrays are objects, too. Unlike other languages, there are no "primitive types" in Ruby. Each value you're dealing with, is an object.
Your line contains a method chain consisting of 3 method calls:
Kernel.gets.match(/\d+/)[0]
#      └──┘ └──────────┘└─┘
#      1    2           3

In a method chain, one method's return value becomes the next method's receiver. Let's examine each one to figure out what [] we have here:

Kernel#gets returns an instance of String (or nil)
String#match returns an instance of MatchData (or nil)
MatchData#[] returns a specific match (or nil)

In your case, [0] returns the first match, e.g.:
input = "123\n"  # <- this could be the return value from Kernel.gets
#=> "123\n"

match = input.match(/\d+/)
#=> #<MatchData "123">

match[0]
#=> "123"


Beat me to it. Might be worth mentioning that if the user input does not contain a number then this code will raise a NoMethodError. I would recommend handling as num = Kernel.gets.match(/\d+/)&.[](0) or next

This actually gets covered in the book: "If a user does not enter a number, the match method in line 3 will return nil, which causes the program to crash out. [...]"

I really appreciate you taking the time to elaborate it for me. Thank you.
